# Prolog: no getting data back

Tags: prolog

I have this program in PROLOG:

```
gd([], 0, [], LSTR) :- write('String: '), write(LSTR).
gd([_|LH], MH, _, ['-'|LSTR]) :- MH == 0, gd(LH, MH, LH, LSTR), !.  
gd([], MH, LB, ['\n'|LSTR]) :-  NH is MH - 1, gd(LB, NH, LB, LSTR).
gd([H|LH], MH, LB, ['*'|LSTR]) :- MH =< H, gd(LH, MH, LB, LSTR).
gd([H|LH], MH, LB, [' '|LSTR]) :- MH > H, gd(LH, MH, LB, LSTR).
```

When I execute `gd([0,2],2,[0,2], S)`.

The output i'm getting is the following:

```
String: _G2343
S = [' ',*,'\n',' ',*,'\n',-,-|_G2343] .
```

So i'm not getting the list back.

¿What i'm doing wrong?.

Thanks you.

Comment: You're passing the 4th argument around with a variable, but the variable never gets instantiated. Your base case, `gd([], 0, [], LSTR) :- ...` writes out `LSTR` but it really needs to define what `LSTR` should be when the other arguments are as stated.

Comment: That's it.Thank-you